# iPhone UITableViewDelegate Question

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a basic question that's driving me crazy.

I have a class inheriting from UITableViewController. It is the root controller in my navigation controller. I have another class that implements the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols (my delegate).

Basically, in my delegate's tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, I want to push a new controller.

When the delegate protocols were simply implemented by the UITableViewController, it was easy:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

I (obviously) can't do that in the delegate class. **How the heck do I refer to the UITableViewController subclass to get access to the navigationController?** It's driving me nuts!

---

Basic Flow:

1. UITableViewController calls delegate
2. delegate runs tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
3. in the delegate's tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, code needs to push new controller onto navigationController
4. delegate does not have reference to navController or the TableViewController to do the push.
5. code gives a compiler error if i try to pass into the delegate the tableController or navController via a property. so, i can't give it a reference back to the calling tableViewController

Comment: a simpler solution might be to not have that extra class at all, and just implement the table view delegate methods in your root controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIApplicationDelegate` should have a reference to the navigation controller. You don't actually need a reference to the `UITableViewController`.

You can simply do something like this:

```
// Get the App delegate
YourAppDelegate * app = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Get the UINavigationController used by the application
UINavigationController * nav = app.navigationController;

// Push the next view controller
[nav pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

Comment: *smacks forehead*

I knew I was overlooking something easy! I'm coming in from Java, so some of hierarchy on how things are put together is still fuzzy :)

Thanks!